# SharpGL controls don't appear in toolbox

Tags: winforms, visual-studio, sharpgl

I have created new WinForm project and have installed SharpGL package for WinForms: `Install-Package SharpGL.WinForms`, but appropriate controls did not appear in toolbox.

How to make them appear?

**note:** This samples https://github.com/dwmkerr/sharpgl/tree/master/source/SharpGL/Samples/WinForms 
already has SharpGL controls in toolbox.

**try_1**: When I click 'choose items...' in toolbox context menu "choose item" window is opened but starts loading and hang visual studio.

**try_2**: I also tryed to set `Options -> Windows Forms Designer -> AutoToolboxPopulate` to `true` and rebuild solution but it doesn't work.

**try_3**: Waited a while in "choose item" window, clicked browse button and navigate to `SharpGLWinForms.dll` in `packages` folder, klicked ok but only `GLColourPiker` had been added into toolbox. (I wanted `OpenGLControl` and other control of this lib)

**try_4**: Repeat **try_3** several times and appropriate controls finally appeared. But why I had repeat this step to get the result. What wrong I did?

Comment: I use Visual Studio 2017

Answer (score 0):

Had same problem.
In order to make designer work with this control I had to make it somehow visible in my Toolbox.

So in my project I:

1. Created new `UserControl` that I named 'GLViewportControl' and made it inherit from `SharpGL.OpenGLControl` instead of plain `UserControl`.
2. Enabled DrawFPS in designer just to check.
3. Rebuild.
4. Designer fails.
5. Rebuild.
6. Designer works.
7. Profit.
8. Good Luck.